# useradd command option [-c comment] does not work

Tags: linux

-c option of useradd command does not work in Linux.
My command is:
**useradd -c Hello fyit** 
Here, Hello is the comment and fyit is the username.
As soon as I press enter after typing this command it shows me the help related to all the options of useradd command.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: error:user fyit already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like,

```
useradd -c "Hello" fyit
```

Comment: No this doesn't work.It shows error message user fyit already exists.

Comment: So, it shows different message now? Then, the command is right by adding quotes for comment. You need to change to another user name if the user is already exists.

Comment: But still it does not work.I tried -c option with usermod option then finally it worked.Anyways thanks.

Comment: u r welcome. If you'd like, you can also edit your question to attach your solution for sharing with others .